# Entry and exit port for Schengen

Tags: visas, schengen, passport-stamps

I received a 90 days multiple entry schengen visa from Hungary in May 2017. I flew from Mumbai to Paris and then further to Budapest. (Therefore, entry stamp at Paris). I spent maximum time in Hungary and then travelled to Italy and flew out from Rome (therefore, exit stamp at Rome). As we can see clearly, my passport has a Hungarian visa but no Hungarian stamps.

I am now applying for another tourist visa to Italy. Would the lack of Hungarian stamps cause a problem or a visa refusal?

Note: my first visa was a french visa and I only went to France and got my passport stamped both times at Paris.

Answer (score 4):

This should not cause a problem. The authorities ought to be well aware that travelers enter and exit the Schengen zone through various airports and catch connecting flights, so it's not at all unusual for a traveler from India to Hungary to arrive and depart elsewhere and not have any Hungarian stamps (indeed, it doesn't look like there are any direct flights from India to Budapest).

The length of your stay and the timing of your next visit could potentially be a concern though. It sounds like you spent the maximum 90 days in the Schengen area and are looking to take another trip almost as soon as you're allowed.  Long repeated stays could cause more scrutiny of your situation, especially if this new trip is a lengthy one as well.